# jQuery mobile style not being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm trying to create a dynamic collapsible list. The data is pulling through the ajax and listing out just fine, but the `jQuery` mobile styling is not being applied and I have no clue how to correct this. I've tried several things that I have found on the internet, but nothing seems to work. Here is the code that I'm using.

```
function button_directory(){
section_directory = document.getElementById("section_directory");
$("#display_area").fadeOut("slow", function(){
    display_area.innerHTML = "";
    title_bar.innerHTML = "DIRECTORY";

    $("#display_area").fadeIn("slow", function(){
    });

    var directoryURL = protocol + domain + "query.php?sid="+code;
    $.ajax({
        url: directoryURL,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(members) {
            if(members.length > 0) {
                temp = '<div data-role="collapsible-set" id="collapsible">';
                $.each(members, function(index, value) {
                    temp +=
                        '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">'+                       
                            '<h3>'+value.firstName+' '+value.lastName+' - '+value.title+'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+value.type+'</h3>'+
                            '<p><strong>Company:</strong> '+value.company+'<br>'+
                            '<strong>territory:</strong> '+value.territory+'<br>'+
                            '<strong>Clients:</strong> '+value.clients+'</p>'+
                        '</div>';
                });
                temp +='</div>';
                display_area.innerHTML = temp;
                $("#collapsible").trigger("create");

                //$("#display_area").find("div[data-role=collapsible]").collapsible();

                //$("#display_area").trigger('create');
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: did u try calling `$(element).collapsible()` ?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. Even tried **$("#display_area").collapsible('refresh');** and **$("#display_area").trigger('create');**

Comment: have you tried: $( "#collapsible" ).collapsibleset( "refresh" );

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the jQuery 1.3 docs?

Take a look at http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-create and see if it helps